# Python fails at installing dependencies while building image

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, pip

Hi I have the below in the requirement file

```
Flask
Flask-PyMongo
google-cloud-storage
pandas
gcsfs
fsspec
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Docker build command

```
docker build -t mycontainer/pythonapp:1.0 .
```

It gets failed at installtion step

```
 2 |     COPY . /app
   3 |     WORKDIR /app
   4 | >>> RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
   5 |     ENV PORT 5000
   6 |     EXPOSE 5000
```

error

```
File "/tmp/pip-install-5kxin4_t/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 294, in build_library_sources
#0 14.39           sources = self.generate_sources(sources, (lib_name, build_info))
#0 14.39         File "/tmp/pip-install-5kxin4_t/numpy/numpy/distutils/command/build_src.py", line 377, in generate_sources
#0 14.39           source = func(extension, build_dir)
#0 14.39         File "numpy/core/setup.py", line 675, in get_mathlib_info
#0 14.39           raise RuntimeError("Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program")
#0 14.39       RuntimeError: Broken toolchain: cannot link a simple C program
```

**EDIT**

I tried including numpy as suggested. Note that i am running the command from google cloud shell

Also i added the command for pip in the Dockerfile. Now error is

```
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 16.23         ERROR: Failed cleaning build dir for numpy
#0 16.23       Failed to build numpy
#0 16.23       ERROR: Could not build wheels for numpy, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
#0 16.23       [end of output]
#0 16.23   
#0 16.23   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#0 16.24 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#0 16.24 
#0 16.24 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#0 16.24 │ exit code: 1
#0 16.24 ╰─> See above for output.
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

added numpy to the requirement file

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior -- your Dockerfile builds without errors on my system. Where are you running the `docker build` command? If you're running it locally, can you tell us about your local environment?

Comment: @larsks I am running this in Google cloud shell

Comment: I tried in google cloud shell in another machine and it works fine. Not sure why it is coming in my current session

Answer (score 0):

To solve your issue you need to add the g++ compiler with `RUN apk add g++`.

So you're Dockerfile will become like that:

```
FROM python:alpine3.7
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk update 
RUN apk add g++
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE 5000
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

I tried it on Cloud Shell and this solves the error.